# query of stores that order all types of products

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my db exists relations:

producttype: `type(PK) | description`

product: `id(PK) | title | type(FK) | price`

orderlist: `(productid(FK), orderid(FK))(PK) | quantity`

order: `orderid(PK) | date | shopid(FK)`

shop: `shopid(PK) | shoptitle | address | phone`

How i must create query to know which shops order all types of product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`.

```
Select s.shopid, s.shoptitle
  From shop s join order o on s.shop_id = o.shop_id
  Join orderlist ol on ol.order_id = o.order_id
  Join product p on p.id = ol.product_id
Group by s.shopid, s.shoptitle
Having count(distinct p.type) = (select count(1) from producttype)
```

Comment: If you expect `count(1)` to be faster than `count(*)` you are wrong - in fact it's actually a bit slower.

Comment: thank u, idk that i can use more than 1 column in group by

Comment: It is just a practise of using 1 . I think 1 and * will give same performance.

Comment: Pls note that `s.shoptitle` is redundant in the `group by` clause because `s.shopid` is primary key and `s.shoptitle` fully depends on it. `Group by s.shopid` is enough.

Comment: But i used it for giving more information, it is upto OP if he wants to use it or not